# webservice call inside oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, salesforce, boomi

Need help in addressing one of the requirement.
Requirement is to call salesforce boomi api as an webservice from oracle trigger and I did implement it, but the problem here is, when the trigger gets fired, salesforce boomi reads oracle data thru oracle view and that view is not fetching any rows, but on oracle it fetches the rows, since there is no data returned from the oracle view on salesforce boomi, it is not writing any thing to saleforce, any recommendation.

Thanks,
Ramprasad.

Comment: I suspect this is about timing, thought it's hard to say without seeing your actual code. If you're expecting Salesforce to see the data being manipulated (that causes the trigger to be fired) that likely won't be possible from a trigger: the trigger fires *within* the confines of the data transaction, so the trigger (and by extension the transaction) won't complete until after the web service call is completed, but the data changes won't be visible until after the transaction is completed and committed. You see the data when selecting from the view because you're selecting after the commit.

Comment: Calling anything *non-transactional* within a trigger is generally a recipe for disaster because triggers can fire *multiple* times even for a single row change. Use the trigger to put the info you need to call the webservice on an AQ, and have a background process to pick up that info from the queue and process it.